# Can I connect to NetSuite data via ODBC without having SuiteAnalytics?

Tags: odbc, netsuite

Just starting a job with a company that uses NetSuite. I am new to NetSuite, and my background is in SQL and C# - I'd like the ability to access the data outside of the UI and wondering if there's a way to do that without asking management to purchase SuiteAnalytics. Their NetSuite consultants of course say I don't need that kind of access but I've already heard the consultants say some reports would be too hard to do - which I know I could easily accomplish with ODBC access and a little code. If I could do it at no extra cost I will truly be a hero.

Comment: While you did remark about not wanting to ask "management to purchase SuiteAnalytics" there are other commercial options available. CData Software (my employer) makes an [ODBC Driver for NetSuite](https://www.cdata.com/drivers/netsuite/odbc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot connect via ODBC without the module.

Comment: Thank you for the direct response. I made my case and the CFO is going to find out about pricing.

Answer (score 5):

There are at least two ODBC drivers available that connect using the SuiteTalk SOAP Web Services API which removes the requirement to purchase SuiteAnalytics.

1. CDATA : [NetSuite ODBC Driver](https://www.cdata.com/drivers/netsuite/odbc/)
2. DevArt : [ODBC Driver for NetSuite](https://www.devart.com/odbc/netsuite/)

Comment: Hey, have any of you used the Native netsuite odbc module?